# Error in theme installation

Tags: magento2, theme

when i am installing a theme I got the following error

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-themes/purity/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To rule out caching try deleting the following directories:

```
var/page_cache
var/di
var/generation
var/cache
var/view_proprocessed
pub/static/frontend
pub/static/adminhtml
pub/static_requirejs
```

And then run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```